# How to Map Google Tag Manager GCP App Engine to AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager

I have a domain on Route53 and just setup a new Server side container for Google Tag Manager.  On Route53 I have the following CNAME record:

```
events.ecruve.com   CNAME   Simple  - https://gtm-5vts3dk-zmu2z.uc.r.appspot.com/
```

Also on GCP I have:

```
events.ecruve.com   Google-managed, auto-renewing - CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com.   events
```

When I try to preview GTM I am getting a 404 error from my app engine server.

```
404. That’s an error.
The requested URL /gtm/debug was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

Is there something else I need to configure for the mapping to work?

Comment: The Internet has great tools for debugging DNS problems. If you cannot share your domain name and exact DNS configuration, do not post a question - use one of those tools. By hiding your DNS information, we can only guess.

Comment: @JohnHanley  I have added in my domains to the question.  Any advice?

Comment: What is the URL, how are you accessing it and what is the error/problem?

Comment: It's 404: https://gtm-5vts3dk-zmu2z.uc.r.appspot.com/gtm/debug

Comment: It's a GTM container: This loads properly. https://gtm-5vts3dk-zmu2z.uc.r.appspot.com/gtm/debug?id=GTM-5VTS3DK&gtm_auth=LuqhitxCSDKfjybvX1kYjA&gtm_preview=env-4 but the events.ecruve.com domain does not

Comment: Did you try other services instead of GCP for sGTM hosting? For example, Stape.io has a much easier domain configuration. Maybe this will be an option for your case https://stape.io/how-to-add-a-custom-domain-to-the-google-tag-manager-server-container/